# Rating, out of ten, between positive and negative votes

Tags: php, mysql, rating-system

I've been wracking my brains for the past several hours on how I would get a rating between 0-10, [see picture](http://i.gyazo.com/0ad0c2aed4100cc16637378a7f65e0da.png), using two values. Positive and Negative votes. I can already grab the votes from the database, and as an example, I'd like to use the following:

```
    Xn = Negative
    Xp = Positive

    50n / 100p
    24n / 12p
    32n / 0p (Would be 0)

     3n / 0p
     2n / 1p
     1n / 2p
     0n / 3p
```

Usually, I'd be rather quick at solving a problem like this. But due to my intense workload, I can't seem to figure it out.

I wouldn't usually ask for such an insane amount of assistance, but, for lack of any decent mathematical skill, I'm turning to you guys for help.

NOTE: The ratings within the picture are defined within a PHP Array. Quite literally the ratings you see. `$ratings = array(5.4,10,7.4,8.3)`

Comment: What is the expected output for your three illustrated cases (the last one being zero)?

Comment: I assume the following: `1: 5.0 | 2: 2.5 | 3: 0` as I said, the above information was just an example. The `positive` and `negative` values would be different accordingly.

Comment: I've added some additional cases.  Can you tell me what the scores for those would be?

Comment: Also, while Populus' answer doesn't give you the scores you want, it *does* give you a rating that is linear over the total range of 0 to 10.  I would have thought that 50/50 would have given you a score of 5, and 24n/12p would have given you a score of 3.33.

Comment: Xp == 0 ? 0 : (Xp / (Xn + Xp)) * 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rating = (Positive / Total Votes) * 10
```

Not sure how it could get any simpler than that...

```
$uvote = 10;
$dvote = 15;
$rating = 0 ? 0 : ($uvote / ($uvote + $dvote)) * 10; // 4
```

Comment: That won't give you 5 for the first case.  It won't give you 2.5 for the second case either.

Comment: he didn't specify that it would be 5, he said `I assume...`

Comment: as in he has no clue what to do, so I'm giving him the simplest solution to his problem: how to get a rating between 0-10 with upvotes and downvotes

Comment: I thank you for that, but then the problem strikes when there's 0 positive votes and, say, 1 negative vote. See, it's trying to divide by zero. Which, according to the laws of the universe, cannot be done.

Comment: if there is 1 negative vote, and 0 positive: `(0 / 1) * 10 = 0`. The case you need to worry about is `0/0`, which I believe PHP just evaluates to `0` by default anyway.

Comment: I suppose I could throw in an automatic positive vote towards the post whenever the uploader posts it. So the person that posted it gets an automatic positive vote towards the post.

Comment: for what it's worth, I think that's what reddit does - your own submissions automatically get one upvote from you.